# Trouble finding the right plugin to animate text

Tags: animation, parallax, gsap, scrolltrigger, locomotive-scroll

For a new project I'm looking for a smooth scroll plugin that animates different elements with parallax effects and more.
Right now I'm using locomotive scroll and it works really nice, but it doesn't work on mobile like I want too.
The effect i'm trying to achieve is something like this:
https://okocha.webflow.io/
The text animating on scroll is something I really want.
I'm writing the website in just plain html, js and css. No cms or other frameworks.
Does anyone know a good plugin I can use to achieve my goals? I'm not really technical. Looked for scrolltrigger js but not finding the thing I want or how to do it. Am i searching wrong here?

Tried locomotive scroll and works great for non touch devices.